# filter results from database by user_id

Tags: django

Hello All I have been trying for days to solve this issue, however I am really not sure where my error is. I am new to django and have been coding for a year. 
I have a model portfolio that takes in tickers and also linked to the user via a foreign key. In my models

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
         ticker = models.CharField(max_length=15)
         user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='investor', null=True)

        def __str__(self):
             return self.ticker
```

my form is as such:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['ticker']
        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['ticker'].queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user)
```

and in my views:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PortfolioForm(request.POST or None, request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticker = form.save(commit=False)
            ticker.user = request.user
            ticker.save()
            return redirect('/add_stock')
    else:
        ticker = Portfolio.objects.filter(pk = request.user.id)
        output = []
        for ticker_item in ticker:
               output.append(str(ticker))
    return render(request, 'test_app/add_stock.html', {'ticker':ticker, 'output':output})
```

I want the user to add stocks to the Portfolio database but only return the stock tickers they added. Currently the stocks are being added to the database but nothing is returned to the user. Also stocks added to the database are available for any user to see not just the specific logged in user. I have added @login_required to the top of the specific view. I'd appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
ticker = Portfolio.objects.filter(pk = request.user.id)
```

to

```
ticker = Portfolio.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

This should return all tickers added by the current user.

Comment: Thank you, so so much, worked like a charm, Thank you again.

Comment: @FrancoisJack Glad I could help. In stackoverflow you are expected to accept the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: Did not realize, thanks for the heads up to follow community rules. Answer accepted. Thanks again.